# Trying to redirect back into MVC from the asp.net Custom Error handler

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

In web.config I have the following code:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/vErrorPages/Error.html">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/vErrorPages/Error404.html" />
</customErrors>
```

In the Error.html I have the following code, where Error is the controller and ErrorPage is the action method:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=../Error/ErrorPage" />
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

This works fine.  It gets me back into MVC where I can provide my custom error page already laid out like the rest of my website.

In reading various SO posts, it seemed like an aspx page with:

```
<% Server.Transfer("../Error/ErrorPage")%>
```

might be faster, so I tried it.  No good.  It gives an 'Error executing child request' error that other SO posts say is effectively the same as an http 404.

If I use the Server.Transfer to access a .html file, it works fine.  It just seems like the MVC routing won't work for this.  I had used the ../ above because of where the .aspx page is located, but this doesn't work either:

```
<% Server.Transfer("~/Error/ErrorPage")%>
```

There were many SO posts on Server.Transfer, but I didn't find one going from .aspx into MVC routing, so I'm asking if anyone has input on this.

**Added after original post for rism below:**  updated web.config section:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/vErrorPages/ErrorGeneral.aspx">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/vErrorPages/Error404NotFound.html" />
</customErrors>
```

This is the entire ErrorGeneral.aspx pointed to by the web.config redirect on error (note: I changed the Error Controller's method name to ErrorGeneral):

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="ErrorGeneral.aspx.vb" Inherits="MVC5ErrorHandling.error1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <% Server.Transfer("/Error/ErrorGeneral")%>
</body>
</html>
```

This does not work either.

Comment: I think you're barking up the wrong tree trying to optimize error pages. They are by definition slow considering all else that will have gone on to generate the exception. Since you already have a working solution do you really want to waste time on this?

Comment: To answer your question, I think I agree re wrong tree; why fix what's working, right?.  But, when one tries to do something and it doesn't work, it seems important to understand why because the learning itself has great value.  To that end, thanks for your answer below.  I'm sure you'll understand it'll take me a bit to study and absorb.  I'll be back...

Comment: Also, I had given thought to the fact that the server.transfer would save a round trip from server to client, but agreed, it's not that big a price given the light weight of error response pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing preventing you from applying the same markup/CSS to Error.vbhtml that you use in _Layout.vbhtml. That being said, instead of redirecting from that page (and you should avoid abusing Server.Transfer anyway), handle the error properly via web.config and the Application_Error event in Global.asax.vb. By doing so, you can show error pages that actually represent the error encountered, rather than some generic "An error has occurred" message.

The required web.config settings are:

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/error/general" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
        <error statusCode="400" redirect="~/error/badrequest" />
        <error statusCode="401" redirect="~/error/unauthorized" />
        <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/error/forbidden" />
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/error/notfound" />
    </customErrors>
</system.web>
```

for IIS 6 and below, and

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
        <remove statusCode="400" />
        <error statusCode="400" path="/errors/badrequest" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        <remove statusCode="401" />
        <error statusCode="401" path="/errors/unauthorized" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        <remove statusCode="403" />
        <error statusCode="403" path="/errors/forbidden" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        <remove statusCode="404" />
        <error statusCode="404" path="/errors/notfound" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

for everything else. The following is a fairly simple implementation of Application_Error:

```
Protected Sub Application_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    Dim exception As Exception = Server.GetLastError()
    Dim httpException As HttpException = TryCast(exception, HttpException)

    Server.ClearError()

    Dim routeData As RouteData = New RouteData()
    routeData.Values("controller") = "error"
    routeData.Values("action") = "general"
    routeData.Values("exception") = exception
    Response.StatusCode = 500

    If Not IsNothing(httpException) Then

        Response.StatusCode = httpException.GetHttpCode()
        Select Case Response.StatusCode
            Case 400
                routeData.Values("action") = "badrequest"
            Case 401
                routeData.Values("action") = "unauthorized"
            Case 403
                routeData.Values("action") = "forbidden"
            Case 404
                routeData.Values("action") = "notfound"
        End Select

    End If

    Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = True

    Dim controller As IController = New Controllers.ErrorController()
    Dim wrapper As HttpContextWrapper = New HttpContextWrapper(Context)

    Dim rc As RequestContext = New RequestContext(wrapper, routeData)
    controller.Execute(rc)

End Sub
```

For this to work, you would need to add an ErrorController and the relevant views.

To address your comment concerning doing something with the exception,  assuming you had defined the General action like so:

```
Imports System.Web.Mvc

Namespace Controllers
    Public Class ErrorController
        Inherits Controller

        Function General(ByVal exception As Exception) As ActionResult
            Return View(exception)
        End Function

        ' ... the rest of the actions 

    End Class
End Namespace
```

Then you could use something as simple as this in the view:

```
@ModelType Exception

@Code
    ViewBag.Title = "Error"
End Code

<h1 class="text-danger">Error.</h1>
<h2 class="text-danger">An error occurred while processing your request.</h2>
<p>
    Exception message: @Model.Message
</p>
```

This example would assume that you want to show the message from the captured exception. You would probably not do that on a live site, but you could add something to check for, say, an administrative-level role and only show the message to those users.

Comment: Starting to work through this. It is a welcomed response (thx) as, believe it or not, this was the very next exercise on my schedule as I work through MVC exception handling.  As I get started, can you confirm if your phrase above, "Authentication_Error event in Global.asax.vb", was simply a typo, or were you trying to make  a separate point apart from Application_Error?

Comment: I successfully ran your posted code.  2 questions: 1 - why do I still need the web.config customErrors redirects since Application_Error is catching all errors and clearing the server? (Except maybe the general redirect for anything odd that 'gets through')  2 - you carefully captured the exception data; how do I recover it in the ErrorController method?  It's all being captured in ELMAH, so I don't necessarily need it in the ErrorController's Views, but I'd still like to understand how to capture in the method.

Comment: I set all three just to be on the safe side, since I want to avoid showing YSODs if at all possible. The last part of the MSDN docs for the HandleErrorAttribute (which you're automatically using with the default project template - check the FilterConfig class) notes one possible reason to set the config values as well: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.handleerrorattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx

Comment: Using your code I was able to capture the exception in the method (I asked for your help because my first attempt didn't work, even though I thought I did exactly what you wrote above, but as often happens, what I thought I did and what I did can be 2 very different things.  But it works!  Thx!  And agreed, not good for live, but I still needed to understand the technique...

Answer (score 0):

The 404 is because the default routing is controller/action/args. So you're asking for a controller named ".." or "~". You should just

```
<% Server.Transfer("Error/ErrorPage")%>
```

and then register the route in the MVC project as:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("MyErrorHandler", "Error/ErrorPage", "~/vErrorPages/Error.html");
```

Although Server.Transfer to an html is a bit odd since you're not going to processing anything else on the server.

Comment: I see now why the route fails when it tries to find the controller for what I posted above.  But your register route suggestion isn't clear to me.  Your suggestion seems to be trying to route to an .html page, but I'm trying to route to a controller method (see 2nd line of text just after the 1st code segment in my post above).  I didn't write it above, but I had tried the .transfer you suggested. I assumed the router should be able to find Error/ErrorPage since they exist, but it still gave an error.

Comment: Try <% Server.Transfer("/Error/ErrorPage")%> If you set a breakpoint in the ErrorPage action on the Error controller does it get hit?

Comment: Actually, I set a breakpoint in ErrorGeneral.aspx on "<% Server.Transfer("/Error/ErrorGeneral")%>".  It fails when I step into it.  You can see the entire file in the edited original post.

Comment: In reading the Microsoft page on the Server.Transfer Method, it states that it sends 'everything' to a second "file".  I previously assumed the MVC router would translate things, but I'm now wondering if the method fails 'on principle' since there is no file extension when specifying an MVC method, yes?

Comment: Do you think it would it be possible to specify a file extension for the route in the .Transfer to allow it to work, then ignore the extension and call the method by setting up a routing statement in RegisterRoutes?